# Nodejs compare two different excel files and spot their difference

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, typeerror

This is my first question. Correct me if i am wrong. I am nodejs new bee. I am trying to compare two excel files via nodejs. I have used excel-compare module to compare two excel files(with multiple sheets indeed). But its throwing type error. Here is my code

```
var excel_compare = require("excel-compare");
excel_compare({
    file1: 'data/school.xlsx', // file1 is the main excel to compare with
    file2: 'data/all.xlsx', // file2 is the file for compare
    column_file1: {
        column: [1],
        join: ''
    },
    column_file2: {
        column: [2],
        join: '-'
    }
})
```

When i run the above code i am getting following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at E:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\excel-compare\index.js:17:35
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (E:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\excel-compare
\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
    at E:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\excel-compare\index.js:15:5
    at Function._.each._.forEach (E:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\excel-compare
\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:82:22)
    at module.exports (E:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\excel-compare\index.js:1
3:4)
    at Object.handle (E:\node_modules\npm\Excel\excelread.js:39:2)
    at next_layer (E:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:
103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\express\lib\router\route
.js:107:5)
    at E:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:213:24
```

Can any one help me to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example on the [excel-compare Github page](https://github.com/chilijung/excel-compare), it looks like you're not specifying the columns properly. Try using a numerical value. I don't think you can compare two worksheets without making some changes to the source.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When i try with numerical value i got the following error
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.

Comment: @user3708542: Make sure you're using numerical values and not string values:

`column: [1]`

rather than

`column: ['1']`

Comment: Tried in the correct manner i mean as column: [1] @sholanozie

Comment: @user3708542: That's strange. Do the files `data/school.xslx` and `data/all.xslx` exist on your machine? Sorry for the obvious question!

Comment: ha ha it exist @sholanozie

Comment: @user3708542: Could you post your updated code here?